# Trying to make a pricing list with jQuery in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've typed the whole calculation. I have a submission button which by clicking needs to retrieve the sum. It doesn't work. I'm pretty new at JavaScript so I can't really tell where is the problem. Here is the code:

```
$('#home_price').submit(function(){
    var shutter_price, lights_price, socket_price, screen10_price, screen7_price, dimmer_price, x
    var total_price = 3000;
    shutter_price = ($('#shutter').val())*200;
    light_price = ($('#lights').val())*200;
    socket_price = ($('#socket').val())*200;
    screen10_price = ($('#screen10').val())*700;
    screen7_price = ($('#screen7').val())*200;
    dimmer_price = ($('#dimmer').val())*400;
    if($('#boiler').is(":checked")==true){
        total_price+=600;
        x+=1;
    }
    x+=($('#shutter').val())*2+($('#lights').val())+($('#socket').val());
    Math.floor(x);
    x+=1;
    total_price = total_price + shutter_price + light_price + socket_price + screen10_price      + screen7_price +           dimmer_price + x*400;
    $('#home_pricing').val()=total_price;
    if($('#home_pricing').val() < 6000)
        alert('the solution invalid');
    else
        alert(" total: " + $('#home_pricing').val());
    });
});
```

and a piece of the html code:

```
    <label for="screen7"> 7inch screen </label> 
    <input style="margin-right:70px" name="screen7" type="number" id="screen7"> <br><br> 
    <label for="dimmer"> dimmer</label> 
    <input style="margin-right:174px" name="dimmer" type="number" id="dimmer"> <br><br> 
    <label for="boiler"> bolier </label>
    <input style="margin-right:148px" type="checkbox" name="boiler" id="boiler" > <br><br> 
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name=" home_pricing " id="home_pricing" value=" calculate " >
    </div>
</form>
```

I tried doing the same with document.getelementbyid(' one_of the id's').value
but still once I pick values in each input line and then click the submission button it just jumps to the window again with no values and doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 1):

Change the submit button's type from 'submit' to 'button'. That way, clicking submit won't redirect you. What you have to do to set the values though, is make an onclick event for the new button.

Instead of using `$('#home_price').submit()`, use `calculate()` and it will work.

Comment: but im still not getting any calculatio result even though the page is not reloading now... when clicking on the button there is nothing going on... like the var's dont get values... any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior when a form is submitted to is to to go to a new page. If no new page is specified, the current page is just reloaded. You can prevent that default behavior in the `submit` event handler method by invoking the event's [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method. To do that, specify an event parameter to the `submit` method definition, then call `preventDefault`, like so:

```
$('#home_price').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Rest of your code here
    // ...
```

**Update**
There are also a couple of obvious errors in your code. The [Math.floor method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) does not modify the variable passed to it, it returns a integer value. Change this line:

```
Math.floor(x);
```

to this

```
x = Math.floor(x);
```

Putting the [jQuery val() method](http://api.jquery.com/val/) on the left side of an assignment does do anything. However, you can pass a value to `val()` and it will set the new value. Change this line:

```
$('#home_pricing').val()=total_price;
```

to this:

```
$('#home_pricing').val(total_price);
```

Comment: but i'm still not getting any result from the calculation itself